# Histogram (hist) not starting (and ending) in zero

Tags: matlab, histogram, probability, probability-density

I'm using the Matlab function "hist" to estimate the probability density function of a realization of a random process I have.

I'm actually:

1) taking the histogram of h0

2) normalizing its area in order to get 1

3) plotting the normalized curve.

The problem is that, no matter how many bins I use, the histogram never start from 0 and never go back to 0 whereas I would really like that kind of behavior.

The code I use is the following:

```
    Nbin = 36;
   [n,x0] = hist(h0,Nbin);
   edge = find(n~=0,1,'last');
   Step = x0(edge)/Nbin;
   Scale_factor = sum(Step*n);
   PDF_h0 = n/Scale_factor;

   hist(h0 ,Nbin)  %plot the histogram
   figure;
   plot(a1,p_rice); %plot the theoretical curve in blue 
   hold on;
   plot(x0, PDF_h0,'red'); %plot the normalized curve obtained from the histogram
```

And the plots I get are:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Take a look at histc (`bar(histc(x,[h0:1/nbins:2]))`)

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is that the *plotted* red curve does not go to zero: you can solve that adding initial and final points with y-axis value `0`. It seems from your code that the x-axis separation is `Step`, so it would be:

```
plot([x0(1)-Step x0 x0(end)+Step], [0 PDF_h0 0], 'red')
```